# HTML: method attribute in anchor tag

Tags: html, anchor

I read in a book, that a `methods` attribute is available on a hyperlink to link to an executable file from within a webpage.

```
<a methods="C:\san\proj.exe">Open This Software</a>
```

But this code is not working on my browser. Does such an attribute exist?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp not that I can see here, also I would be interested to know which book this is

Comment: I know the 'method' attribute on a form or the 'formmethod' on an input but never heard of the 'methods' attribute on an anchor. Maybe you need to buy another book ;)

Answer (score 3):

The `methods` attribute is extremely out-of-date. For example, it is mentioned in the [1995 W3C Archive](http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/1995-archive/Elements/A.html) for Anchor Elements as follows:

> `METHODS`
>   OPTIONAL. The value of this field is a string which if
>   present must be a comma separated list of HTTP METHODS supported by
>   the object for public use.

However, it is no longer part of the specification, which likely explains why your browser is not behaving as you expect. For example, the [W3C Spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html) now states the following permitted attributes for `<a>` elements:

```
<!ELEMENT A - - (%inline;)* -(A)       -- anchor -->
<!ATTLIST A
  %attrs;                              -- %coreattrs, %i18n, %events --
  charset     %Charset;      #IMPLIED  -- char encoding of linked resource --
  type        %ContentType;  #IMPLIED  -- advisory content type --
  name        CDATA          #IMPLIED  -- named link end --
  href        %URI;          #IMPLIED  -- URI for linked resource --
  hreflang    %LanguageCode; #IMPLIED  -- language code --
  rel         %LinkTypes;    #IMPLIED  -- forward link types --
  rev         %LinkTypes;    #IMPLIED  -- reverse link types --
  accesskey   %Character;    #IMPLIED  -- accessibility key character --
  shape       %Shape;        rect      -- for use with client-side image maps --
  coords      %Coords;       #IMPLIED  -- for use with client-side image maps --
  tabindex    NUMBER         #IMPLIED  -- position in tabbing order --
  onfocus     %Script;       #IMPLIED  -- the element got the focus --
  onblur      %Script;       #IMPLIED  -- the element lost the focus --
  >
```

As a general rule, you cannot run executable scripts directly from a web browser (thankfully). The only option you have is to link directly to the `exe` file using the anchor's `href` attribute, and have the visitor download the file via their browser. It is then their decision if they chose to run the executable or not. This would be achieved as follows:

```
<a href="C:\san\proj.exe">Open This Software</a>
```

It is worth noting that the path you've specified here (i.e. `C:\sans\...` is a local path, and will need to be modified when your project becomes available online.

Answer (score -1):

You need to specify the protocol. In your case is `file://` but I don't recommend to link to your hard disk if you publish the webpage in `http://`

The correct attribute is `href`:

```
 <a href="file://C:\san\proj.exe">Open This Software</a>
```

Comment: *Don't recommend linking to your hard disk if you publish the webpage*? How would that work then, using `file://`?

Comment: If the webpage is published anywhere other than a local server, the `file://C:\san\` URL will try to to look for a file on the visitor's local machine, so no, it's not true.

Comment: If the webpage is under `file://` protocol, there aren't no servers running. But your point about visitor's machine is true. That doesn't converts my answer in false.

Comment: But you specifically stated that you don't *recommend* using `file://` with `http://` when it's published on the open web...